# java.io.FileNotFoundException: In Netbeans glashfish server

Tags: java, servlets, netbeans, glassfish, servlet-3.0

I'm very new to JAVA. I tried to save image through Java servlet and Ajax in netbeans. In netbeans I tried same coding with tomcat server is working fine.If I use Glashfish it's throwing error. Below is my coding.

**Servlet:**

```
 @Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
   Part img = request.getPart("img");
        String id = (String) request.getParameter("ids");
        out.println(saveImage(img, "E:\\Users\\XXXX\\Desktop\\wine_shop\\build\\web\\images\\wines"));
}
```

**Save image method:**

```
private String saveImage(Part img, String path) throws IOException {        

    File fileSaveDir = new File(path);
    if (!fileSaveDir.exists()) {
        fileSaveDir.mkdirs();
    }
    System.out.println("Upload File Directory=" + fileSaveDir.getAbsolutePath());

    String fileName = null;

    fileName = extractFileName(img);
    img.write(path+ fileName);
    return "1";
}
```

**My Error:**

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2\config\GF_4.1.1\domain1\generated\jsp\wine_shop\E:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\wine_shop\build\web\images\winesth.jpg (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
```

Help to fix this..

Comment: That filename looks invalid to me... `E:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2\config\GF_4.1.1\domain1\generated\jsp\wine_shop\E:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\wine_shop\build\web\images\winesth.jpg` It has 2 `Drive` labels in it.

Comment: Yeah. But the file path also incorrect because of the glassfish server. It's working fine with Tomcat.

Comment: i guess there is something wrong with your `extractFileName` method which might be corrupting file name.

Comment: it's giving exact file name. I tried print it.

Comment: extractFileName gives=th.jpg and path gives E:\Users\XXX\Desktop\wine_shop\build\web\images\wines

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code..

```
@WebServlet(name = "abc", urlPatterns = {"/upload"})
@MultipartConfig
public class abc extends HttpServlet {
private final static Logger LOGGER =
            Logger.getLogger(abc.class.getCanonicalName());

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
       final String path = "E:\\shopping\\web\\admin\\img";
    final Part filePart = request.getPart("file");
    final String fileName = getFileName(filePart);

    OutputStream out = null;
    InputStream filecontent = null;
    final PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(new File(path + File.separator
                + fileName));
        filecontent = filePart.getInputStream();

        int read = 0;
        final byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        while ((read = filecontent.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            out.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        writer.println("New file " + fileName + " created at " + path);
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "File{0}being uploaded to {1}",
                new Object[]{fileName, path});
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fne) {

        writer.println("<br/> ERROR: " + fne.getMessage());

    } 
}

private String getFileName(final Part part) {
    final String partHeader = part.getHeader("content-disposition");
    LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Part Header = {0}", partHeader);
    for (String content : part.getHeader("content-disposition").split(";")) {
        if (content.trim().startsWith("filename")) {
            return content.substring(
                    content.indexOf('=') + 1).trim().replace("\"", "");
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```